# Convert VARCHAR in format 35:23:12 to an datatype i can sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have varchar data that is in the below format:

Example 1 - 00:00:06

Example 1 - 372:25:27

It represents hours:minutes:seconds

i need to be able to convert it to a data type i can sum it i want the hours and minutes alone.
Is there anyway to convert this data so that i can sum it with a query?

N.B i can not change the tables doing some work on someone else's DB.

Comment: please add more examples and results that you expect

Comment: the examples i put is how the data is stored in the DB so i want :
My data 372:25:27 = 372 
i can work with the hour values alone, not sure how i could work it out to get both hour and minutes query wise 
Basically the numbers before the first :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex will split your string so u can work with them

```
select 
regexp_substr('123:20:20' ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) HOUR,
regexp_substr('123:20:20' ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) MIN,
regexp_substr('123:20:20' ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) SECOND
from dual;
```

Comment: i get error -ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: i copied wrong error see below 
column name STATUSTRACKING

ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
01850. 00000 -  "hour must be between 0 and 23"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: also it is not a time it is how long something took so in my example 2 -
 372:25:27 it took 372 hours and 25 minutes and 27 seconds

Comment: It would be perfect if i could get hours and minutes and a way to separate them i need to calculate how long routines take so if i could get hours on one column and minutes to another would be ideal !!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Walucas showed, you can use regular expressions to extract the hour, minute and second parts of your string values (assuming they are all formatted the same way):

```
select statustracking,
  regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as h,
  regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1) as m,
  regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1) as s
from your_table;

STATUSTRACKING H         M         S        
-------------- --------- --------- ---------
00:00:06       00        00        06       
372:25:27      372       25        27
```

then convert them to numbers and multiple the elements to get them all representing the number of seconds (say), and add those together for the total number of second represented by the string:

```
select statustracking,
  3600 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)) as h,
  60 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1)) as m,
  to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1)) as s,
  3600 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1))
    + 60 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1))
    + to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1)) as total_s
from your_table;

STATUSTRACKING          H          M          S    TOTAL_S
-------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
00:00:06                0          0          6          6
372:25:27         1339200       1500         27    1340727
```

then sum those totals:

```
select sum(
    3600 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1))
      + 60 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1))
      + to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1))
  ) as total_s
from your_table;

   TOTAL_S
----------
   1340733
```

then reverse the conversion process to break that total number of seconds down into hours, minute and - if you want them - seconds:

```
select floor(total_s / 3600) as h,
       floor(mod(total_s, 3600) / 60) as m,
       mod(total_s, 60) as s
from (
  select sum(
      3600 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1))
        + 60 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1))
        + to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1))
    ) as total_s
  from your_table
);

         H          M          S
---------- ---------- ----------
       372         25         33
```

If you want to go back to your string format you can concatenate those back together with colons, left-padding with zeros either with `lpad()` or `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(total_s / 3600, 'FM9999900')
       ||':'|| to_char(mod(total_s, 3600) / 60, 'FM00')
       ||':'|| to_char(mod(total_s, 60), 'FM00')
       as total_time
from (
  select sum(
      3600 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 1))
        + 60 * to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, null, 1))
        + to_number(regexp_substr(statustracking ,'(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 3, null, 1))
    ) as total_s
  from your_table
);

TOTAL_TIME      
----------------
372:26:33
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=179c2b24d3d5535822ab5952ea566cae)

Comment: Thank you for the advice this works perfectly for my needs.